# JBoss EAP 7.1 + Spring Boot Application: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank'

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, jboss-eap-7

I'm attempting to deploy a Spring Boot (2.0.2) application on JBoss EAP 7.1 server.

The code that's causing the problem is:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Component
@Validated
public class AppProperties {

  @NotBlank
  private String name;
```

When the application is deployed on JBoss I get the following exception:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
16:44:25,861 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6 7)

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'app' to com.example.security.config.AppProperties:

    Property: app.contextpath
    Value: /api
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml]:5:18
    Reason: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'name'

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

I've tried adding the file jboss-deployment-structure.xml with the following contents to WEB-INF/classes:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
  <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
      <subsystem name="jaxrs"/>
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="javaee.api"/>
      <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
      <module name="javax.faces.api"/>
      <module name="org.hibernate.validator"/>
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But, no luck. What's the workaround? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Even though this question is a year old, I ran into the same issue and couldn't find a solution.

This, I know, will work for Spring Boot 2.1.x and JBoss 7.1, not sure about versions before that.

We obviously need to exclude `org.hibernate.validator` and `javax.validation.api`. What wasn't clear is that we also need to exclude the `javax.faces.api` (it has a transitive dependency on `javax.validation.api`). Excluding that javax.faces causes JBoss to fail on start up due to missing jsf libraries. We can then simply exclude the `jsf` subsystem.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jsf" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.validation.api" />
            <module name="javax.faces.api" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Assuming you don't need JSF from jboss, this should work.

Comment: This worked for me on Spring Boot 2.2.3 and JBoss 7.0.0. Note also that having excluded the jsf subsystem I did not need to explicitly exclude javax.faces.api.

Comment: Jboss 7.1
spring 2.17
 above solution worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-JBossDeploymentStructureFile) the jboss-deployment-structure.xml shoudl be placed in 'the top level deployment, in META-INF (or WEB-INF for web deployments)'.

So with your current set-up the things configured in the xml are not applied, so if the xml is put in the right location it might work.

Comment: Thanks Sven. I've tried multiple combinations for the location of the file and none of them work.

Comment: Have you put the config file directly in the webinf folder? I saw you mentioned in the classes folder, but it might make a difference if it is directly in the webinf?

Answer (score 0):

`javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank` is part of Bean Validation 2.0 and thus Java EE 8. I suspect EAP 7.1 does not support this feature yet.

Comment: I'm unable to find any documentation that states which version of Bean Validation is supported in JBoss EAP 7.1. It's odd that it isn't easy to decipher.

Comment: Sorry about that. EAP 7.1 [is a certified implementation of the ... Java EE 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/pdf/introduction_to_jboss_eap/Red_Hat_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform-7.1-Introduction_to_JBoss_EAP-en-US.pdf) standard. And Bean Validation (JSR 380) is part of [Java EE 8](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/).

Comment: Thanks Martin Freidank.