# Missing Validators on tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, tomcat

I am attempting to use hibernate validators with SpringBoot and Tomcat and yet continue to get this error

```
No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank'
```

I tried adding the following to my maven pom.xml without luck

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-RC2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

It works locally when started by java so how can I fix this? I found this issue [[HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty' validating type 'java.lang.String'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52608600/hv000030-no-validator-could-be-found-for-constraint-javax-validation-constrai) but it didn't seem to fix my problems whenever I double checked that hibernate-validator was at version 7.

File causing issue can be seen here https://github.com/OntoloBridge/ontolobridge-project/blob/Authentication/src/main/java/edu/miami/schurer/ontolobridge/models/User.java

Here is my dependency Tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.2:tree (default-cli) @ 

ontologbridge ---
[INFO] edu.miami.schurer:ontologbridge:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.10:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.5:runtime
[INFO] +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.20:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.34:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.34:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.34:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.15.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.7.11:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- it.ozimov:spring-boot-email-core:jar:0.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-core:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:jar:2.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-keyvalue:jar:2.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.lettuce:lettuce-core:jar:5.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- it.ozimov:embedded-redis:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.owasp.encoder:encoder:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:21.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.opencsv:opencsv:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.22.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- io.sentry:sentry:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] +- io.sentry:sentry-logback:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:7.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish:jakarta.el:jar:4.0.0-RC2:compile
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.el:jakarta.el-api:jar:4.0.0-RC2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator-cdi:jar:7.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
```

Comment: Hibernate validator 7 is a jakarta validation api implementation. You need version 6 not 7. Spring (Boot) doesn't support JakartaEE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to have been the spring-boot-email-core

```
[INFO] +- it.ozimov:spring-boot-email-core:jar:0.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.3.Final:compile
```

Adding the following to the dependency fixed it

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```